# Locus of tangent lines to a smooth curve of degree $d$ and genus $g$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, tangent-line, intersection-theory, schubert-calculus

Suppose $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^3$ is a smooth curve of degree $d$ and genus $g$ (let's say we are working over $\mathbb{C}$). Let $T(C)$ be the locus of tangent lines to $C$. In other words,
$$
T(C) = \{ L \in\mathbb{G}(1, 3) \ | \ L \text{ is tangent to C}\}
$$ 
Here $\mathbb{G}(1, 3)$ is the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$. How can I compute the class of this locus $[T(C)]$ in the Chow ring? More precisely, what does $[T(C)]$ look like in $A^{3}(\mathbb{G}(1,3))$?

Attempt: We know that $[T(C)]=c \sigma_{1, 2}$ where $\sigma_{1, 2}$ is the Schubert cycle corresponding to lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that pass through a point $p$ and contained in a plane $H$ (where $p$ and $H$ are general but fixed). So we just need to figure out the constant $c$. To do this, can fix a general line $L_{0}$, and intersect this class $[T(C)]$ with the Schubert cycle $\sigma_{1}$ (which consists of all lines incident to $L_0$). Thus, $c$ is equal to the number of lines $L$ that is tangent to $C$ (at some point) such that $L\cap L_{0}\neq\emptyset$. How can we determine this number in terms of the degree $d$ and genus $g$ of the smooth curve $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across to the following beautiful argument in [*Notes on Grassmannians and Schubert Varieties*](http://server.maths.umanitoba.ca/~jaydeep/Site/Papers_files/GrSc.pdf) by Chipalkatti (see page 27).

Given a general line $L\subseteq\mathbb{P}^3$ we want to compute the number of tangent lines to $C$ that intersect $L$. Pick a general line $M$ (which will be skew to $L$) and consider the projection away from $L$, i.e. consider the map
$$
f: C \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 \cong M
$$
given by sending $x\in C$ to the intersection of $M$ and the plane $\overline{Lx}$ (generated by $L$ and $x$). Now we will apply the Riemann-Hurwitz theorem!

What is the degree of $f$? Given a general point $y\in M$, it is easy to see that
$$
f^{-1}(y) = \{x\in X: x \in \overline{Ly}\cap C\}
$$
which consists of $d$ distinct points (where $d$ is the degree of $C$), because $y\in M$ was general. Moreover, since $L$ and $M$ are general, the ramification points $f$ will have degree $1$ (i.e. simple ramification points). The ramification points of $f$ are exactly those points $x\in C$ such that $L$ meets the tangent line $\ell_{x}$ to $C$ at $x$. So Riemann-Hurwitz tells us 
$$
2g - 2 = d(2\cdot 0 - 2)+\text{# ramification points}
$$
Thus, the number of tangent lines that meet $L$ is precisely:
$$
2g + 2d - 2 = 2(g+d-1)
$$
We conclude that
$$
[T(C)] = 2(g+d-1) \sigma_{1,2}
$$
in the Chow ring of $\mathbb{G}(1, 3)$.